# Is there a way to create a new image transform 'onAfterInstall()' of a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, image-transforms

As the title suggests, I would like my plugin to generate a new image transform automatically (with a few settings) when the plugin is installed.

The purpose is to avoid my plugin from crashing if a transform hasn't already been generated yet (or doesn't have the same handle names).

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the method [actionSaveTransform](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/controllers/AssetTransformsController.php#L77) in the [AssetTransformsController](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/controllers/AssetTransformsController).

The code you actually need for your `onAfterInstall` would be like this:

```
// Only create if it doesn't exist (by handle)
if (is_null(craft()->assetTransforms->getTransformByHandle($handle))) {
    $transform = new AssetTransformModel();
    $transform->id = $transformId;
    $transform->name = $name;
    $transform->handle = $handle;
    $transform->width = $width;
    $transform->height = $height;
    $transform->mode = $mode;
    $transform->position = $position;
    $transform->quality = $quality;
    $transform->format = $format;

    if(craft()->assetTransforms->saveTransform($transform)) {
        // Success
    }
    else {
        // Error
    }   
}
```